# How to get a 'month' field with query_set?

Tags: python, django

I have a model and it has a field 'month'. How do I get this field with query_set?

Model is returning a field called 'area' and I don't want to change it to month because I need field area for another function's query_set.

Field 'month' has name of month ex: 'January'.

my model

```
class Report(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Created by: ')
    year = models.IntegerField('Year:', default=2019)
    month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Month', null=True, choices=MONTHS.items())
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    new_ministers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.area)
```

my views.py or my function:

```
def report_list(request):
    areas = Report.objects.all()

    context = {
        'areas':areas

    }
    return render(request, 'users/report_list.html', context)


def report_month(request):
    month = Report.objects.all()

    context = {
        'month': month
    }

    return render(request, 'users/report_month.html', context)
```

Comment: You just need `month` column value from `Report`?

Comment: @shafik That's right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` which returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

```
month = Report.objects.values('month')
```

You can write custom template tag.
For example, if your custom tags/filters are in a file called `month_name.py`, your app layout might look like this:

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        month_name.py
    views.py
```

And in your template you would use the following:

```
{% load month_name %}
```

Then write this for get month name

```
import calendar
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter("month_name")
def month_name(month_number):
    return calendar.month_name[month_number]
```

Then in your template

```
{{ month|month_name }}
```

Comment: I tried `month = Report.objects.values('month')` but what I get is only numbers ( 1, 2 )

Comment: can you add the exact result obtained after performing `Result.objects.values('month')`